# Sqlite add column based on another columns value

Tags: sql, sqlite, ddl, calculated-columns, alter

I have a first_name field in an SQLite database. 
I want to alter this database by adding a first_initial column and make its value the first character of first_name followed by a period.
How do would I go about setting the value of first_initial, can it be done from the alter statement?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN first_initial TEXT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this cannot be done as part of the `alter` statement. However, you could follow up the `alter` statement with an `update` statement to initialize the initial:

```
UPDATE mytable SET first_initial = SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1);
```

Or better yet, if the `first_initial` is always the first character of `first_name`, you don't need it in the table at all - you could just query it on demand, or, if you prefer, create a view to retrieve it:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT *, SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1) AS first_initial
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain why this can not be done with the `Alter` statement? Newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do what you want for any new rows entered (after adding the column as you do in your alter statement). It may need a little tweaking, so here's the reference page on triggers: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_first_initial_default_value
AFTER INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.first_initial IS NULL
BEGIN
  UPDATE mytable
  SET first_initial = substring(NEW.first_name,1,1)
  WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

However, I'm also inclined to say that you really shouldn't have a duplicate column with dependent information, because it adds a lot more complexity than it does value (in my opinion).

Any time you need to get the first initial, just do this:

```
SELECT substring(first_name,1,1) AS first_initial FROM mytable
```